# Making a two dimensional arraylist

Tags: arrays, arraylist

I would like to make a two dimensional arraylist.
Currently I have an arraylist which displays all values. 
I would like to put these values in arraylist of arraylist which would look like this:
from `[value1,value2,value3,value4,value5,value6]`

to
`[[value1,value2,value3],[value4,value5,value6]]`

How can I achieve this?

Thanks in advance

Edit: So I have an Arraylist with the some random values (string)
`[**Activity_Name,Activity,Name**,value4,value5,value6,value7,value8,value9]`

I would like to group every 3 values in another arraylist which would look like this:
`[[value1,value2,value],
[value4,value5,value6] etc`

But at the moment it only gives me the value of the first 3 components so:
[[activityname,activity,name],
[activityname,activity,name] etc

Comment: What programming language are you using? Java?

Comment: What language are you using? Also do you need to transform the array or create it by hand this way?

Comment: I am using java @xander ,  I get an arrayList with [value1,value2,value3,value4,value5,value6] and want to transform it to   [[value1,value2,value3],[value4,value5,value6]]

Comment: Im using java @cdaiga

Comment: Ok so what is your problem? Depending on the data type you need you can just use `ArrayList<ArrayList<Object>>` !?

Comment: can u give an example, because when i tried it , didnt work. Adding an arraylist for every 3 values :/ @xander

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple example, a list of list of integers:

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> a = new ArrayList<>();
a.add(new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3)));
a.add(new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(3, 4, 5)));
System.out.println(a);
```

Output:

> [[1, 2, 3], [3, 4, 5]]

Is that what you want, just some simple array lists, it's a bit ugly to add a list to another list like this, but just `Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3)` doesn't work in Java.

Ok here my extended answer, it divides the list in 3 element sublists, you can use `ArrayList.subList` for that:

```
ArrayList<String> src = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9"));
ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> dst = new ArrayList<>();

for (int i = 0; i < src.size(); i+=3) {
    dst.add(new ArrayList<>(src.subList(i, i + 3)));
}

System.out.println(dst);
```

Output:

> [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]

Comment: how would you do it then? I want an arraylist containing a few other arraylists of Strings. @xander

Comment: @Hye with Strings it's exactly the same, just replace Integer with String and then use strings in the lists. Maybe you mean something different, then change your question with another example.

Comment: sorry not good at explaning but, I have an arraylist with values and with those values I need to make a few arraylist. But at the moment, it just gets value1, value 2 and value 3 of the arraylist. I added an edit

Comment: I have added an extended version, I guess that is what you want!? :)

Answer (score 0):

Say you want to create a 2D arraylist of strings you can do the following in Java 8.

```
public class Test {

  public static void print2DStringList(List<List<String>> twoDList){
      if(twoDList != null){
         System.out.println("*****2D list content*****");
         for(List<String> sublist: twoDList){
            for(String str: sublist){
                System.out.println(str);
            }
            System.out.println("-----------");
         }
      }
  }

  public static void main(String... args){

     List<List<String>> twoDList = new ArrayList<>();

     for(int i=1; i <= 2; i++){
        twoDList.add(new ArrayList<String>());
        for(int j=1; j <= 3; j++){
          twoDList.get(i).add("Sub list " + i + " item " + j);
        }
     }

     System.out.println("=> Initialize List");
     print2DStringList(twoDList);

     //Adding an item into sublist2 of twoDList 
     twoDList.get(1).add("Here is another item");

     System.out.println("=> After adding another item");
     print2DStringList(twoDList);

     //modifying the first item of sublist1 of twoDList 
     twoDList.get(0).set(0,"***Sub list 1 item 1***");

     System.out.println("=> After modifying the first item of sublist1");
     print2DStringList(twoDList);

  }

}
```

That's just the logic

Comment: I get what you mean but if i have a list of values that have to be added and I dont know how much. I would like to loop over it such like in an array : list[0].get[0] , so that u get the first row, fill it and get the second row and fill it, until the array has ended @cdaiga

Comment: There you go, it's simple.

Comment: Vote up my answer.